# What are valid and invalid pixel units?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I would like to create a textbox to capture the width of an image from the user.

This measurement should be in pixels, what sort of validation should I use when capturring the pixel unit?

Is it simply a valid INT value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The pixel value should be a valid `INT` number and if you give value in `decimal` the decimal part will be get truncated.

You can give decimal number if you use `percentage` for specifying the width. The percentage will evaluate to proper pixel size of the parent element.

Comment: is there any documentation for this?

Comment: @shenku You can refer this http://elasticss.com/determination-of-algorithms-used-for-percentage-based-rounding-divs-on-browsers-and-css-frameworks/